# Domain is currently unable to handle this request 500

Tags: php, apache, centos

[domain] is currently unable to handle this request. When I try to install IPBoard, iv'e installed IPBoard multiple times on multiple servers and never had this issue, but maybe iv'e missed something out that I ain't noticed.

I have installed LAMP

Linux - Centos 7
Apache2
MySQL
PHP - 5.4

and then I allowed 10000 // 80 // 433 for Webmin and Apache and I put a simple home.html and info.php files in the /var/www/html/ directory and both load the pages correctly.

But when I upload the files from IPBoard to /var/www/html/ via FTP (filezilla) and load the webpage I just get 'Domain is currently unable to handle this request 500' and I'm not sure why maybe config in the PHP or something ?

Any help is great thanks!

Error log:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function IPS\mb_internal_encoding() in /var/www/html/init.php on line 124

line 124:

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

Comment: Apache typically outputs any issues to its error log (`/var/log/apache2` or something) for 500 errors. Check there and update us with the contents of it  if it doesn't set you on the right path.

Comment: completely forgot about that thanks i'll update in a minute

Comment: centos would likely be `/var/log/httpd/`.

Comment: yeah i found it, iv'e updated with the line now, i'm also having a quick google in case it's obvious fix, also i'll put the line it says there's an error on

Comment: You need to install the [mbstring](http://php.net/mbstring) extension. `yum install php-mbstring` (the php part might include a version like `php54-mbstring`).

Comment: yeah i have just found that out via google, my biggest issue today was forgetting to check error log thanks!

Comment: I am having the same issue but no logs are generated in /var/log/apache2